# Parse search text in to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, reactjs

**What I try to create:**

I have 1 input where user can search for data. He can search like this `cats` or he can search with labels like this `author:Stan cats year:1990` (will look for cats shot on camera in 1990 whos author is Stan). When user wrote `author:Stan cats year:1990` it should be replaced with components

```
<div>
  <Label type="author" value="Stan"/>
  <p>cats</p>
  <Label type="year" value="1990"/>
</div>
```

**How I think this can be realized:**

1. Parse `author:Stan dogs cats year:1990` and put into array in order of how it was written:

-

```
[
  {
    type: "author",
    value: "stan"
  },
  {
    type: "text",
   value: "dogs cats"
  },
  {
    type: "year",
    value: "1990"
  }
]
```

-

2. `map` array and check the type of every entry - if it's not `text` return `<Label/>`:

-

```
array.map(({ type, value }) => {
  if (type === 'text') {
    return <p>value</p>
  }
  return <Label type={type} value={value} />
})
```

-

**Problem:**

Parsing `author:Stan dogs cats year:1990` into array with **order of how it was written**. I still don't know how to do it properly, because if for example, we apply `regex` then the order will not be applied.

I hope someone has some ideas.

Comment: Do please change the weird title that makes no sense: `Parse not simple text in to massive
`

Comment: Ok, done. Better ?

Comment: What does it mean? It is not proper English - what is `massive` in this contexxt?

Comment: "Parse search text in to Array" would be better

Comment: Sorry, my bad, fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You no doubt *could* do this with regex - your assumption that order wouldn't be preserved is odd - but you could do this using an old-fashioned split and reduce

```js
var input = "author:Stan dogs cats year:1990";

var result = input.split(' ').reduce(function(p,c){
    // determine if we have a label
    if(c.indexOf(':')>-1){
        var items = c.split(':');
        p.push({type:items[0], value:items[1]});
    }
    else{
        // determine if previous item was text - if so add the value
        if(p[p.length-1].type == "text"){
           p[p.length-1].value += ' ' + c
        }
        else{
           p.push({type:'text',value:c});
        }
    }
    return p;
    
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to test for edge cases, and ultimately I don't think it's a very good system, but I think the below should put you on a good start.

```js
let input = 'author:Stan dogs cats year:1990';

let splitInput = input.split(/\s+/);

let searchTerms = [];

const parseTextSearch = (textSearchArray) => {
  return {
    type: 'text',
    value: textSearchArray.join(' ')
  };
};

const parseCurrentTerm = (term) => {
  let key = term.split(':')[0];
  let value = term.split(':')[1];
  return {
    type: key,
    value: value
  };
};

let textSearch = [];

for (let i = 0; i < splitInput.length; i++) {
  let currentTerm = splitInput[i];
  if (/\:/.test(currentTerm)) {
    if (textSearch.length > 0) {
      searchTerms.push(parseTextSearch(textSearch));
      textSearch = [];
    }
    searchTerms.push(parseCurrentTerm(currentTerm));
  } else {
    textSearch.push(currentTerm);
  }
  if (i === splitInput.length - 1 && textSearch.length > 0) {
    searchTerms.push(parseTextSearch(textSearch));
  }
}

console.log(searchTerms);
```